# Git Merge by file type

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two git branches, master and mybranch. Mybranch has all the correct *.json files, and master has all the other file types correct. How do I merge them?

There are many, many merge conflicts in all the files. If I could somehow merge by file type, I wouldn't have to go through all the merge files.

Answer (score 4):

`git checkout` has options `--ours` and `--theirs` to get the respective versions during a merge. So you do something like

```
git checkout master
git merge mybranch
git checkout --theirs -- *.json
git checkout --ours -- <the-other-files>
git add .
git commit
```

where you'll have to play with the shell a bit to list the files you want to take from one or the other branch. After you check out the desired versions to the work tree, `add` should clear the conflict records.

Remember, `--ours` is the branch that you passed as argument to initial `checkout` and `--theirs` is the branch that you passed as argument to `merge`.

Also, before you call `add`, you can change your mind with the `--ours` and `--theirs`, because the index still contains all the versions. So you should be actually able to do `git checkout --ours -- .` and then `git checkout --theirs *.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Given you want to merge `Mybranch` in master, general advice would be:

```
git checkout master
git merge Mybranch
```

If there are merge conflicts - resolve them.

It is **recommended** to perform often a rebase onto master or a merge to the local branch in order to avoid a huge amount of merge conflicts when you are ready to bring changes from your local branch into master.

**UPD:** The fastest solution would be using diff patch:

1. Checkout master branch.
2. Create a diff patch only for JSON files.

   `git diff master Mybranch  *.json > json.diff`
3. Apply diff.

   `git apply json.diff`
4. Commit changes.

*Notes*:
If there are conflicts in working directory - patch won't apply. Might be helpful to make for several or every JSON its own diff in order to localize problematic json file. For conflicting diff you could open a diff file and edit it before applying. Either way - if there are conflicts, you **must** solve them.

Comment: Yes, there are many, many merge conflicts in all the files. That is why I am asking about merging by file type. I know in advance which ones are correct by file extension. Do I really need to go through all the merge files? <<<<<<< yours:sample.txt
Conflict resolution is hard;
let's go shopping.
=======
Git makes conflict resolution easy.
>>>>>>> theirs:sample.txt